# Can't run zend framework MVC application on WAMP

Tags: zend-framework, wamp

I am new to zend framework application. I got a book online with it's source code example and I'm trying to work on in to learn about zend framework mvc. I extracted the example folder in www in wamp. When I try to reach the application localhost/exampleMVC/ I get a page with all folders in that directory except for the public, the one should be available for the server and when I try to access it localhost/exampleMVC/public I get an error page Error 500; internal server error.

what do I miss!?

thanks

Answer (score 8):

simply you missed to enable `mod_rewrite` to solve it go to

```
WAMP -> APACHE -> apache modules -> then click on the mod rewrite
```

you would notice that apache restart itself 
and you be good to go

i did a screencast about zf + wamp setup before 2 years , you are welcome to watch  it 
http://www.zendcasts.com/getting-started-with-zend-and-wamp-server/2009/06/

Comment: mod rewrite was disabled , that is it :) easy breezy

Comment: I mean, why was mod rewrite being unchecked prohibiting me from seeing the website or the public folder?

Comment: I had noticed that rewrite was disabled by default on wamp server fresh installation

Comment: Dude, that isn't my question. Why did I have to uncheck mod rewrite? What does that do? You said, "simply you missed to enable mod_rewrite to solve it go to", but WHY do I have to do that?

Comment: Jesus, every freakin project, I have to waste half an hour, browsing and changing httpd.conf and the one in extra, just to remember about activating mod_rewrite on wamp. They should come with this thing on by default. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure a `virtual-host` in apache to make zend work properly with mode_rewrite

in your `wamp\bin\apache\Apache(version number)\conf\httpd.conf` remove the `#` symbol in front of the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` (just under the line `# Virtual hosts` near the end of the config file)

Then in the file `wamp\bin\apache\Apache(version number)\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` there should be something like that :

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
#NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#

nameVirtualHost localhost
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

after this, add your new virtual host, something like that :

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\zendProject\public\"
    ServerName zendProject.local
    ErrorLog "logs/zendProject.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/zendProject.local-access.log" common
    <directory "C:\wamp\www\zendProject\public\">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

make sure to replace `zendProject` by your actual zend project name. I personnaly add the `.local` as the domain extension, this way I wont override a real domain on the Web.

And finally to make it work you need to edit your host file, which should be located there : `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

you just have to add at the end of the file the following line (open it in notepad) :

```
127.0.0.1       zendProject.local
```

make sure to use the same name that you've setted in your virtual host configs.

Restart your Wamp server and you are good to go