# Setup VirtualHost for Zend Application on Wamp server

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, wamp, virtualhost

I'm following this tutorial to learn how to start a project using ZendFramework

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

When I get to setup a virtual host I get stuck. If I do exactly as the tutorial says, it shows me an error (in all my project, zend or not), says the file wasn't found.

Then I found this tutorial on StackOverflow very handy

[Can't run zend framework MVC application on WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298112/cant-run-zend-framework-mvc-application-on-wamp)

Following what the guy on the bottom of the page says takes me to the same error when I try to access my app as `zendProject.local/`

This is what I got

on hosts (Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts) file

```
127.0.0.1       blog.local
```

on httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerName blog.local
DocumentRoot /blog/public

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

<Directory /blog/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? The browser still says **Not Found The requested URL /public was not found on this server** when I go to `http://blog.local/`

I'm running WAMP on Windows. And this is the absolute path to the 'blog' project `C:\wamp\www\blog`

@Edit RiggsFolly

this is what I got now in the *httpd-vhosts.conf* file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"

    <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        # make sure this is only allowed to be accessed by the local machine
        # then if/when you open one of your other sites up to the internet and somebody uses your IP
        # they will get directed here as its the first VH def and then receive a 403 not allowed to access
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/websites/blog/public"
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory "C:/websites/blog/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted        
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And I created a new directory at C:/ called 'websites' as you suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be a little more specific with your folder locations. I guess this tutorial was written for Unix and you are using windows.

For Apache 2.2.x use this syntax:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/blog/public"
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/blog/public">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You would be better avoiding the `Allow from all` and using `Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1` until you actually want to allow the universe to see your sites.

For Apache 2.4.x use this syntax:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/blog/public"
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/blog/public">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted        
</Directory>
```

**Note** `NameVirtualHost *:80` no longer required for Apache 2.4.x

Again you would be better avoiding the `Require all granted` and using `Require local` until you actually want to allow the universe to see your sites.

**EDITED After comment from Questioner:**

Right, that's the Apache default. If you enter a url it cannot find a Virtual Host definition for it will default to the first Virtual Host definition you gave it, the blog in your case.

Ok, so now you need to create a Virtual Host for each of your other projects, and MOST IMPORTANTLY the **first one** needs to be `localhost` and only be allowed to be accessed from the local PC for a bit of extra security.

Now personally I would take this opportunity to move my actual sites to a totally separate folder structure outside the \wamp\ folder structure so there is no confusion with rights given to the \wamp\www folder and my other sites.

So for example, create a folder `c:\websites\www` and in that folder create a folder for each of your projects eg

```
c:\websites\www\blog
c:\websites\www\project2
```

Then point your virtual hosts to the relevant folder containing the site code ( this can be on another disk if you like ). This allows you to specify the Apache security ( who is allowed in to this site) specifically for each of your VHOSTS. So when you want a client or friend to be able to play with one site, you just change the security on that one site while you let them play.

Like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"

    <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        # make sure this is only allowed to be accessed by the local machine
        # then if/when you open one of your other sites up to the internet and somebody uses your IP
        # they will get directed here as its the first VH def and then receive a 403 not allowed to access
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/websites/www/blog/public"
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory "C:/websites/www/blog/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted        
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project2.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:/websites/www/project2"
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    <Directory "C:/websites/www/project2">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        # this site also available to other PC's on my internal network
        Require ip 192.168.0
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Remember, for each new Virtual Host site you create you also need to add that ServerName (project2.dev) to the hosts file.

```
hosts file:
127.0.0.1  blog.local
127.0.0.1  project2.dev
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: hey, man! thank you! I did what you said and it's working. But now if I try to go to any of my other projects apache redirects to the ZendApplication (using localhost). What do I need to do to see the Blog App only if I go to localhost/blog ?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Now after adding the localhost directive it is working like I did nothing, just like before starting to set up VirtualHosts. Do you know why? How am I supposed to access the Blog with this new configuration? @edit have a look at my latest edit on the post

Comment: Well if I got it right, you should be able to use `http://localhost` to get to the WAMPServr home page and `http://blog.local` to get to your bloging site.

Comment: IF when you use `http://blog.local` it goes to the WAMP Homepage then there is something wrong with the VHOST definition for blog.local

Comment: when I use `blog.local` it says the URL wasn't found on the current server. This is the message, notice the **/** on *The requested URL / was not found on this server*

Comment: it's working now (i don't know what I did to fix the previous problem, I just restarted apache again and now it works)

Comment: Probably restarted Apache. Need to do that so it picks up these changes