# Working with local and live websites. issues with subfolders in www folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp, wampserver

I have a live site, example.com and when i have pulled it off to a local enviroment using wampserver i am having some issues

on the live site everything works ok and if I click on a link it will resolve properly

```
example.com/offices
```

However on the localcopy because I have other sites in the www folder(as subfolders) I have to access it by

```
127.0.0.1:8888/example/
```

and when I click on the same link on the local website it will go to

```
127.0.0.1:8888/offices/
```

instead of

```
127.0.0.1:8888/example/offices/
```

And the same goes with images as the are all looking for folders in the root rather than the subfolder (www/example)

I have tried using virtual hosts and couldn't get it to work

is there a rule I can put in the htaccess or would I need a seperate install of wamp so it all resides in the www folder?

Comment: Virtual Hosts are the best way to go, try this to help get them working properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719300/setup-virtualhost-for-zend-application-on-wamp-server/21724384#21724384

Comment: Revisited them and tried again and it worked properly this time, thanks @RiggsFolly